# Where does this unspecified error comes from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, winjs, windows

I'm trying to format any kind of variables to achieve some kind of `toString()` method.

It's working for pretty complex objects and arrays, handling circular references, but when I try to call it on a jQuery object: `format($("body"))`, for testing it on large complex objects, I got this error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 330, column 21 in ms-appx://8b94d51c-586e-4f3f-bb9c-fa75d62508cd/js/default.js

0x80004005 - Erreur d’exécution JavaScript: Erreur non spécifiée.
0x80004005 - JavaScript Run-time Error: Unspecified error. // I translated it for you
```

Here is my code (with a `// ERROR!` comment next to the line `330`):

```
function format(arg, parents, indent) {
    var maxParent = 25;
    if (parents === undefined) {
        parents = [];
    }

    if (indent === undefined) {
        indent = 1;
    }

    if (contains(parents, arg)) {
        return '<span class="brackets">[Circular]</span>';
    }

    if (typeof arg === 'string' && parents.length > 0) {
        return '"' + htmlEntities(arg) + '"';
    } else if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
        parents.push(arg);

        if (parents.length >= maxParent) {
            return '<span class="brackets">[Array]</span>';
        }

        var ret = "[ ";
        for (var i = 0, len = arg.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (i !== 0) {
                ret += ", ";
            }

            ret += "<br>";
            ret += addIndent(indent);

            ret += format(arg[i], parents, indent + 1);
        }

        ret += "<br>";
        ret += addIndent(indent - 1);
        ret += " ]";

        return ret;
    } else if (arg === null) {
        return '<span class="void">null</span>';
    } else if (arg === void 0) {
        return '<span class="void">undefined</span>';
    } else if (typeof arg === 'number' && (isNaN(arg) || !isFinite(arg))) {
        return '<span class="void">' + arg.toString() + '</span>';
    } else if (typeof arg === 'object' && arg !== null) {
        if (parents.length >= maxParent) {
            return '<span class="brackets">[Object]</span>';
        } else {
            parents.push(arg);
        }

        var ret = "{";

        var first = true;

        for (var key in arg) {
            if (!first) {
                ret += ", ";
            }
            else {
                first = false;
            }

            ret += "<br>";
            ret += addIndent(indent);
            ret += key;
            ret += ": ";

            if (typeof arg[key] === 'function') {
                ret += '<span class="brackets">[Function]</span>';
            } else {
                ret += format(arg[key], parents, indent + 1); // ERROR!
            }
        }

        ret += "<br>";
        ret += addIndent(indent - 1);
        ret += "}";

        remove(parents, arg);

        return ret;
    }

    return arg;
}
```

Do you have any ideas why this error is occuring?

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Break it down a bit. Do you know exactly which jquery property it is acting on when it fails? `console.log(arg,key,arg[key])`

Comment: 0x80004005 generally means 'Access denied'.  Make sure that your code isn't accessing a property that it doesn't have access to.

Comment: @KevinB The last one is `[object HTMLDocument] onpointerup null`

and `console.log(parents)` is `[object Object],[object HTMLBodyElement],[object HTMLHtmlElement],[object HTMLDocument]`

Comment: Ah. so it came across the `document` (which is stored on `$().context`) and is failing on one of the event properties.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, but I can't see why it's failing here. There is a lot of other `document` stuff before this. It iterates a lote before failing (`format` is called >2661 times).
And even if it cannot access something like @T.V. said, I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Is it the first event property it tried to access? I have no problem accessing it in chrome.

Comment: Not at all. Right before, there is: [...], `[object HTMLDocument] onpointerout null`, `[object HTMLDocument] onpointerover null`, and then `[object HTMLDocument] onpointerup null`, *crash*.

Comment: Does calling `format(document.onpointerup)` directly give you the same error?

Comment: No, it totally works :/ (Thanks for your help, btw)

Comment: In these situations, I've resorted to (gasp!) `debugger` in Chrome. Once I put it somewhere in code close to (or at the start of) an area of code that blows up, I then step line-by-line and see where it's choking.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the top of my head I can think that arg[key] is null by the time you call the format function. Synchronize the if statement so it executes only after arg[key] is not null.

Comment: You had a nice intuition. I made a condition right before the recursive call like this:

`if (arg[key] !== null)`

But now, the exception is trown in the condition. @T.V. was probably right. The access seems to be denied. Weird.